# python >= operator on classes

Tags: python, operator-overloading, built-in

I have a question regarding python '>=' behaviour.

I have an old TimeStamp class, which holds (hour, minute) tuple and offers some methods such as `__eq__`, `__gt__`, `__lt__`.

I am refactoring it to also account for day and second, and to store the data as total seconds. Here I implemented `__eq__`, `__gt__`, `__lt__` as well.

However, further in code I am using >= operator for this class and while the old class version is working properly, with the new one I am getting

```
TypeError: unorderable types: TimeStamp() >= TimeStamp() error.
```

Code is below:

```
class TimeStamp(tuple): # OLD, WORKING VERSION
    """TimeStamp, hh:mm tuple supporting comparison and addition"""
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:  # tuple entrance
            hour, minute = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2: # hour, minute entrance
            hour, minute = args[0], args[1]
        else:
            raise TypeError('wrong input to TimeStamp')
        div, minute = divmod(minute, 60)
        hour += div
        _, hour = divmod(hour, 24)
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (hour, minute))

    @property
    def abs_min(self):
        return self.hour * 60 + self.minute

    def __gt__(self, rhs):
        return self.abs_min > rhs.abs_min

    def __lt__(self, rhs):
        return self.abs_min < rhs.abs_min

    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return self.abs_min == rhs.abs_min
```

New version:

```
class TimeStamp:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for argument in args:
            if not isinstance(argument, int):
                raise TypeError("Can only build TimeStamp from ints, not: " + str(argument))

        if len(args) == 1:  # init by abs
            self.abs = args[0] # put the ELEMENT, not the tuple itself
        elif len(args) == 2:    # init by hour:minute
            hour, minute = args
            self.abs = hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60
        elif len(args) == 4:    #init by day:hour:minute:second
            day, hour, minute, second = args
            self.abs = day * 24 * 60 * 60 + hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second
        else:
            raise TypeError("wrong data for TimeStamp: " + str(args))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, TimeStamp):
            return self.abs == other.abs
        else:
            raise TypeError("wrong argument for comparison: " + str(other))

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, TimeStamp):
            return self.abs > other.abs
        else:
            raise TypeError("wrong argument for comparison: " + str(other))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, TimeStamp):
            return self.abs < other.abs
        else:
            raise TypeError("wrong argument for comparison: " + str(other))
```

Now for the comparison part:

```
if args[1] >= self.start:
>>TypeError: unorderable types: TimeStamp() >= TimeStamp()
```

I have found two fixes: first, to replace my comparison line with

```
if args[1] > self.start or args[1] == self.start:
```

or an alternative, to add

```
def __ge__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, TimeStamp):
        return self.abs >= other.abs
    else:
        raise TypeError("wrong argument for comparison: " + str(other))
```

to my new class. However, the old one did work with neither of those fixes. It looks to me as if Python stopped deducting that ((a>b) or (a==b)) implies (a>=b). But why did it work before? Does it have something to do with me subclassing tuple?

PS. don't be scared by my `__init__` code, which I included for completeness. It's supposed to be overload-like, but I might be doing it in a non-pythonic way (still learning)

Comment: What happens if you make TimeStamp inherit from `object`?

Comment: You also might want to check out `functools.total_ordering` to prevent you from having to write all the rich comparison methods yourself.

Comment: Final comment -- Rather than raising `TypeError`, you should return `NotImplemented` -- There's no reason to tell other classes that they shouldn't be able to be compared to a `TimeStamp` if they know how to do it.  (It also eliminates funky errors like `time_stamp > my_class` raising TypeError, but `my_class <= time_stamp` working just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old one worked because it inherited from `tuple`, and `tuple` provides `__ge__`.  Your new version does not inherit from `tuple`, so it doesn't have a `__ge__` method.

Even in your old version, your `__gt__` and `__lt__` methods were never being called when using `>=` (as you can verify by putting `print` inside those methods).  The underlying `tuple.__ge__` was being called instead.  However, for your case, the effect is the same, so you didn't notice.  That is, given that the "minutes" number is always less than 60, comparing `(hours, minutes)` tuples in the usual way is equivalent to comparing `60*hours + minutes`.  So I don't think you really need to define the comparison methods at all if you inherit from tuple.

Comment: So, to clarify: Python in fact does not make the automatic assumption that
   (a > b) || (a == b)     is equivalent to (a>=b)
? I was kind of suspecting that, but docs [link](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html)
says
Instances of a class cannot be ordered with respect to other instances of the same class, or other types of object, unless the class defines enough of the methods __lt__(), __le__(), __gt__(), and __ge__() (in general, __lt__() and __eq__() are sufficient, if you want the conventional meanings of the comparison operators).
which would mean lt and eq should be enough

Comment: That is correct; Python does not make that assumption.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__), which says: "There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators."  In the documentation you linked to, "can be ordered" means "you can come up with a way to order them"; it doesn't mean "Python will come up with a way to order them for you".  If you write `>=`, `__ge__` is called.  If you only defined `__gt__` and `__eq__`, you *can* order the objects, but you have to do it explicitly by using `>` and `==` separately.